# Javascript hiding dropdown menu buttons

Tags: javascript, html

After Struggling I have installed a multiple layer drop down menu. When all is well I found that all the buttons like present on my website [Please Click Here](http://www.fedri.com/bh/) are hiding. I found its the issue with javascript present in my html head. Please solve this issue...

HTML HEAD CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#mega-menu-7').dcMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '3',
        speed: 'fast',
        effect: 'slide'
    });
});
</script>
```

If you want jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.js and jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js files I will sent to you.

Also, there is a splitter on the totally right hand side of my menu about 1mm which goes beyound the page. Can we delete it ????

Thanks for your support.

Comment: From the style _body,html,div,blockquote,img,label,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,form,a,fieldset,input,th,td{border:0;outline:none;margin:0;padding:0;}_ remove _input_ to get the normal look for buttons

Comment: Also  removing _ border-right: 1px solid #44b3ff;_ from _.green ul.mega-menu_ may give some relief to the second problem...

Comment: Great A.V its working fine for the buttons.. thanks you. Yes I remove the border right, there is still a small extend outside the page. can you help for this also.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having.

Comment: Hi barmar; if you see the dropdown menu totally right side,there is small around 2mm extended outside the page. I am trying to remove it..can u help in this...

Comment: Try setting .green _ul.mega-menu { width:99.9%}_ and _.green ul.mega-menu li a {width: 101.75px}_

Comment: @user1820652 If you were successful with my answers , I will post as answer so that you may mark it as answer.. ???